# OpenCV imwrite() not saving image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to save an image from OpenCV on my mac and I am using the following code and so far it has not been working.

```
cv::imwrite("/Users/nickporter/Desktop/Gray_Image.jpg", cvImage);
```

Can anyone see why this might not be saving?

Comment: What does 'not been working' mean? building error? runtime error? or you could not find the stored image?

you could either: check the return value of this function, or display the `cvImage` to see if the image is correct.

Comment: When I say not working, the code is compiling fine but I see no image saved to my destination.

Comment: what's the return value of this call? could the `cvImage` be displayed by `imshow`?

Comment: I tried `imshow` and get a lengthy exception. Check out my question over here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/29895/imshow-throwing-exception-osx/

Comment: it seems that your library has some problem. sorry that i don't know how to solve it in MAC. what about `cvShowImage`? you could write a simple c program to test `load` and `cvShowImage`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OpenCV does have problems in saving to `JPG` images sometimes, try to save to `BMP` instead:

```
cv::imwrite("/Users/nickporter/Desktop/Gray_Image.bmp", cvImage);
```

Also, before this, make sure you image `cvImage` is valid. You can check it by showing the image first:

```
namedWindow("image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("image", cvImage);
waitKey(30);
```

Comment: I've been trying to save a bloody jpg image for the longest time.... Tried everything I can think of, changed to .bmp and suddenly it works. Thank you dude, bloody MVP!

Comment: I was doing the exact same, Sipty! How frustrating haha. That's a bummer jpg's are not working

Comment: I wish the solution fixed writing to a jpg instead of this band aid.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Changed file extension to `.bmp` and it magically started working. OpenCV 3.4 *facepalm*

Comment: Very strange. Saving to png worked some time back. It suddenly stopped working. Saving to bmp works ;)

Comment: Just close all windows that were opened by imshow and you'll have your image saved either jpg or bmp

Answer (score 11):

I met the same problem and one possible reason is that the target folder to place your image. Suppose you want copy A.jpg to folder `"C:\\folder1\\folder2\\"`, but in fact when `folder2` doesn't exist, the copy cannot be successful(It is from my actual test, not from official announcement). And I solved this issue by checking whether the folder exists and create one folder if it doesn't exist.  Here is some code may it help using c++ & boost::filesystem. May it help.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>  
#include <iostream>
std::string str_target="C:\\folder1\\folder2\\img.jpg";

boost::filesystem::path path_target(str_target);
boost::filesystem::path path_folder=path_target.parent_path();//extract   folder
if(!boost::filesystem::exists(path_folder)) //create folder if it doesn't exist
{
  boost::filesystem::create_directory(path_folder);
}  
cv::imwrite(str_target,input_img);
```

Answer (score 3):

I also suggest to check folder permissions. Opencv quietly returns from imwrite without any exception even if output folder doesn't have write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem, loading in a jpg and trying to save it back as a jpg. Added this code and it seem to be fine now.

```
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(100);
```

And you need to include the param in your writefile.

```
cv::imwrite("/Users/nickporter/Desktop/Gray_Image.jpg", cvImage, compression_params);
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV 3.2 imwrite() seems to have a problem to write jpg file with Windows Debug mode. I use this way instead of imwrite().

```
cv::Mat cvImage;

#ifdef DEBUG

IplImage image = IplImage(cvImage);
cvSaveImage("filename.jpg", &image);

#else

cv::imwrite("filename.jpg", cvImage);

#endif
```

Comment: I have jpeg writing problem on linux with opencv imwrite() on 3.2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be dropped into your code to support writing out jpg images for debugging purposes.

You just need to pass in an `image` and a `filename` for it. In the function, specify a path you wish to write to & have permission to do so with.

```
void imageWrite(const cv::Mat &image, const std::string filename)
{
    // Support for writing JPG
    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back( CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY );
    compression_params.push_back( 100 );

    // This writes to the specified path
    std::string path = "/path/you/provide/" + filename + ".jpg";

    cv::imwrite(path, image, compression_params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not true for your case. This problem may arise if the image path given as argument to the cv::imwrite function exceeds the allowed maximum path length (or possibly allowed file name length) for your system.

for linux see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs

for windows see: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-character-limit-for-file-names-in-windows-10