# Save output image in jpg format - OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I want to save my output image in **.jpg format only**, because then I use the same image to execute another code, which requires its image in .jpg format. I used imwrite function, which gives me Unhandled exception: Access violation reading location. When I tried to save the same in .bmp format it works fine. 
My example code taken from [here](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/opencv-example-to-load-and-display-image.html):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Mat image;

    // LOAD image
    image = imread("image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file "image.jpg".
    //This file "image.jpg" should be in the project folder.
    //Else provide full address : "D:/images/image.jpg"

    if (!image.data)  // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //DISPLAY image
    namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("window", image); // Show our image inside it.

    //SAVE image
    imwrite("result.jpg", image);// it will store the image in name "result.jpg"

    waitKey(0);                       // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

This code also gives same error. Is there any way I can save image in jpeg format only.

Reference:
1. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369168/opencv-imwrite-not-saving-image) that shows we can save the image in .bmp format.
2. I have downloaded openCV 3.0 and not built it on [own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287117/opencv-imwrite-params-read-access-violation). So I think this solution is ruled out.
3. My error is something similar to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9247/access-violation-with-imread/) code. But the solution here does not work.

I use OpneCV 3.0, Visual studio 2013, Windows 8.1. 
Error got:
[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you really have to use `opencv_world300.dll` in your project? I ran your code and I did not use that DLL at all. Also, try adding `opencv_imgcodecs300.dll` to the same directory as your CPP file.

Comment: It works when `opencv_ffmpeg300.dll` is added to the folder where .exe is present as stated by @Humam Helfawi. Yes, @Rowen I removed `opencv_world300.dll` and works fine. But I didn't find `opencv_imgcodecs300.dll`.