# imwrite opencv function always return false when i want to save frame in sdcard JNI C++

Tags: c++, opencv, java-native-interface, android

I'm using opencv in android unsing JNI c++ and i want to detect image and save detected face in android sdcard using function provide by opencv in c++ imwrite() but when i compile all thing succeded but when i excute app imwrite doesn't work it return false even though i use permission in manifest file (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) .
i'm sorry about any mistakes in english because it not my original language.
help please and vote up please because this project is very important to me

this is the code :

```
String human_cascade_name = "/storage/extSdCard/OpenCV/haarcascade_fullbody.xml";
CascadeClassifier human_cascade;

//-- 1. Load the cascades
      if( !human_cascade.load( human_cascade_name ) ){
      printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
       return;
        }
std::vector<Rect> humans;
     Mat frame_gray;

     cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
     equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

     //-- Detect faces
     human_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, humans, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
     stringstream ss;
     static int count=0;


     for(int i=0;i<humans.size();i++){


     //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh : %d ",humans[i].y);

     Point center( humans[i].x + humans[i].width*0.5, humans[i].y + humans[i].height*0.5 );
     ellipse( frame, center, Size( 2, 2), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

     rectangle(frame,Point(humans[i].x,humans[i].y),Point(humans[i].x+humans[i].width,humans[i].y+humans[i].height), Scalar(0,255,0));

       }
       count+=1;
       ss << count;
       vector<int> compression_params;
       compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
       compression_params.push_back(9);
       if(imwrite("/storage/extSdCard/OpenCV/User1.jpg", frame)){
       __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "yes");

       }else{
       __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LOG_TAG", "no");

       };


      }
```

Comment: This doesn’t appear to have anything to do with JNI. I suggest you debug it as a straight C++ application first; it might simplify things.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369168

Comment: Another possible duplicate (although it appears you have already checked for this): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291504

Answer (score 0):

You see the path to sdcard as `/storage/extSdCard` in **adb** shell or in your file transfer program on PC, but your Android app does not have access through this path. It should use the `getExternalStorageDirectory()` API, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40205116/192373).