# OpenCV 4.5.5 CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY

Tags: c++, image, opencv, jpeg, image-compression

I am working on a project for which I need to combine few images, The end result is an Image with resolution (120849, 296). In my Project, I am trying to save this image to my local disk in the jpg format using the imwrite() function. But it is not working for me. No error or exception is given by my current code.
The only solution that worked for me was this one.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369168/opencv-imwrite-not-saving-image)

Which is not what I want. Can anyone tell me, how can I save the image in jpg format in OpenCV 4.5.5 using compression parameters? I think this might be the solution that I need.

Comment: "resolution (120849, 296)"? does the **JPEG format** even support that resolution? AFAIK it does not. what does your question have to do with CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY? you put it in the title, please explain.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating this monster ? (You must be combining several thousand "normal" images)

Comment: I am thinking with the help of image compression I might be able to get the jpg, but the issue is i am unable to get the quality compression parameter in openCV 4.5.5 which is under the enum  CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY. That why the title is this.

Comment: @Yves_Daoust the reason  is, I have small chunks of images that are parts of a single image. I want to re-split the image into a different chunk size. Originally the images are of width 734 pixels but now I want 241. So I was thinking to combine and then split the image to the required chunk size.
 Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: @Christoph_Rackwitz Yes this resolution is supported. From what I have googled " The max supported resolution is (65,535, 65,535)". mine is well under this limit, overall.

Comment: 120,000 exceeds 65,535 and will prevent it working. The limit is 2-bytes (16 bits) for width. And 2-bytes for height. Read the limits as meaning neither height nor width may exceed 65,535.

Comment: I understand now, I thought the limit was on total pixels. But still I need to know, how to use the compression parameters in openCV 4.5.5